# How to find optimum split panes in k-d tree without brute force

Tags: algorithm, optimization, raytracing, kdtree

I'm using a k-d tree for spatial partitioning in a ray tracer. When determining where to divide a given rectangular region, I choose the dimension with the longest size of the region and then look for the best split pane by checking all the boundaries of the axis-aligned bounding-boxes of the intersecting primitives along that dimension. For complex scenes this requires an enormous amount of checks. Is there a way to narrow down the search for the best split pane so that all the potential positions don't have to be checked, but still get the best pane?

I determine the "best" pane by finding the pane with the lowest value given the following formula:

```
TRAVERSE_COST + INTERSECT_COST * ((l_area/area * l_count) + (r_area/area * r_count))
```

where `area` is the surface area of the rectangular region being split, `l_area` and `r_area` are the surface areas of the left and right regions that would be produced by splitting the current region at the given position and `l_count` and `r_count` are the numbers of primitives the left and right sub-regions would contain. A primitive that intersects the split pane is considered to be contained in both sub-regions, thus `l_count + r_count` may be greater than the number of primitives in the current region (`TRAVERSE_COST` and `INTERSECT_COST` are just constants that were determined by testing different values). This method seems to work quite well.

My implementation is based on a paper called *Realtime Ray Tracing and Interactive Global Illumination* by Ingo Wald and in it he states that the optimum split pane lies between the region's center and the "object median", but my own tests indicate that the pane with the lowest value of the aforementioned algorithm will often fall outside this range, even if I interpret "object median" as the entire range of the median primitive's AABB. This could be due to any number of differences in implementation since I only used the paper for implementing the k-d tree building and traversal, not for the rest of the ray tracer.

Comment: Maybe you're already doing this, but if not, here's an idea: for each rectangular region, keep 3 sorted lists of AABB opposing face pairs, one list for each dimension.  For whichever dimension you choose, you can then sweep through the sorted list of face pairs for that dimension, considering each as a possible "split pane".  You can quickly calculate the number of AABBs each "pane" would split as you go -- it's just the number of "left" AABB faces for which you haven't seen the matching "right" AABB face yet.  Also generating the 3 lists for the 2 resulting subregions is linear time.

Comment: Yeah, I already sort the primitives to make calculating the counts trivial, but thanks anyway.